# Why cannot pass the address of lambda function to another function here?

Tags: c++, c++17

When I ran the code below I got a "bad_function_call" thrown

```
void fn(void* f) {
    auto fu = static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(f);
    (*fu)();
}

int main() {
    auto f1 = [] () {
        std::cout << "f1";
    };

    fn(&f1);
}
```

Of course code would work if I wrote:

```
void fn(void(*f)()) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    auto f1 = [] () {
        std::cout << "f1";
    };

    fn(f1);
}
```

but it fails when passing `&f1` as a `void*` and converting it to `std::function<void()>*`.

What's the correct way if I want to do this?

Comment: You are lying to your compiler. A lambda is not an `std::function<void()>`. A lambda *can be converted* to an `std::function<void()> ` but these are still two different things.

Comment: You can imagine a lambda as a struct with some members (captures) and `operator()(...)`.

Comment: I am curious if I just want to pass `&f1` as a `void*`, what's the correct way to do it? I also tried with `auto fu = static_cast<void(**)()>(f);`. It won't throw `bad_function_call` but still won't print `"f1"`

Comment: Lambda, `std::function` and function pointer (`void(*)()`) are three distinct types (some conversions might exist between them).

Comment: Don't try to pass any lambda function as a `void*` argument. You will be unable to use it then because *the type of any lambda is unique*, so it is impossible to `static_cast` it back to its original type. Generally speaking, avoid `void*` altogether in C++, `std::byte*` is a good replacement for it when dealing with raw memory buffers.

Comment: @prapin The idea is to have the lambda decay to a function pointer, pass it as void*, and cast it back to the function pointer.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili except that *capturing* lambdas can't decay into a function pointer. And technically, function pointers are not allowed to be casted to `void*` in C++, though some compilers allow it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the one in this example is not capturing, and I have an answer below pointing out that you can't convert a function pointer to a void*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second version of your code is ok because a lambda without capture can be converted to a function pointer. This conversion is from the type of the lambda to the type of the function pointer.

Once you converted the lambda to a `void*` you left the type system. There is no proper conversion from `void*` to a function pointer. To do this you would first need to cast the `void*` back to the type of the lambda, and then this can again be converted to a function pointer.

Your faulty code is similar to this:

```
  int x = 42;
  void* p = &x;
  float y = *static_cast<float*>(p);
```

Expecting the last line to make a proper conversion from `int` to `float` is wrong. The `void*` carries no information on what the actual type of the object is. `static_cast<float*>(p)` pretends that `p` would point to a `float` but it does not.

In modern C++ there is no reason to use `void*` for type erasure anymore. Only when interfacing legacy code that expects a `void*` you may need to resort to such unsafe casts. For other cases of type erasure, there is `std::any`, `std::variant`, `std::function`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert function pointers to `void*` in a portable way. You might be able to get away with this with `memcpy` but I wouldn't recommend doing so, as that causes undefined behavior.

Unportable code below, please don't use it:

```
template <class R, class ...Args>
void* to_void_ptr(R(*fp)(Args...)) {
   void *result;
   static_assert(sizeof(result) == sizeof(fp));
   memcpy(&result, &fp, sizeof(result));
   return result;
}

template <class Fn, st::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<Fn>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
Fn* to_function_ptr(void* p) {
   Fn* fp;
   static_assert(sizeof(p) == sizeof(fp));
   memcpy(&fp, &p sizeof(fp));
   return fp;
}
```

Comment: This is mostly a theoretical issue, I believe. `dlsym()` returns `void *` and nobody seems to mind.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is of course possible (I added an example) but it's not portable.

Comment: My point is, even if you just cast the pointer, this should be portable enough in real life, if even POSIX mandates it (through `dlsym` returning `void *`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C++ runs on non-posix systems and even without an OS sometimes.